# Python REST API using FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, status

from api.database import database, user_table
from api.models.user import UserIn
from api.security import authenticate_user, get_password_hash, get_user, create_access_token

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/register", status_code=201)
async def register(user: UserIn):
  if await get_user(user.email):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="A user with that email already exists")
  hashed_password = get_password_hash(user.password)
  query = user_table.insert().values(email=user.email, password=hashed_password)

  await database.execute(query)
  return {"detail": "User created"}

@router.post("/login")
async def login(user: UserIn):
  user = await authenticate_user(user.email, user.password)
  access_token = create_access_token(user.email)
  return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

User router

```
import datetime

from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import ExpiredSignatureError, JWTError, jwt 
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from api.database import database, user_table

SECRET_KEY = "2b31f2a"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"])

credentials_exception = HTTPException(
  status_code=401, 
  detail="Could not validate credentials", 
  headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"}
)

def access_token_expire_minutes() -> int:
  return 30

def create_access_token(email: str):
  expire = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
  jwt_data = {"sub": email, "exp": expire}
  encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(jwt_data, key=SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
  return encoded_jwt

def get_password_hash(password: str) -> str:
  return pwd_context.hash(password)

def verify_password(plain_password: str, hashed_password: str) -> bool:
  return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

async def get_user(email:str):
  query = user_table.select().where(user_table.c.email == email)
  result = await database.fetch_one(query)
  if result:
    return result

async def authenticate_user(email: str, password: str):
  user = await get_user(email)
  if not user:
    raise credentials_exception
  if not verify_password(password, user.password):
    raise credentials_exception
  return user

async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
  try:
    payload = jwt.decode(token, key=SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    email = payload.get("sub")
    if email is None:
      raise credentials_exception
  except ExpiredSignatureError as e:
    raise HTTPException(
      status_code=401, 
      detail="Token has expired", 
      headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"}
    ) from e
  except JWTError as e:
    raise credentials_exception from e
  user = await get_user(email=email)
  if user is None:
    raise credentials_exception
  return user
```

Security module

So the way it is configured right now makes it difficult to implement a logout, and the way it's implemented right now forces us to use get_user several times if we were to hold a column called session_active to implement logout, or a column called secret to hold the secret so we can logout, but then as I've said we need to call get_user several times if we were to do that, so I am wondering if there's any issue with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## secrets in the source ?!?

```
SECRET_KEY = "2b31f2a"
```

This is a problem.

Delete the line.
And generate a new key, invalidating the old one.
Secrets go into a vault, an HSM, or maybe into env vars or a text file.

Source repos like `git` are good at many things,
but managing secrets is not one of them.

Maybe we wish to use the identifier `PEPPER` for this secret?

## hash vs cleartext

```
  query = user_table.insert().values(email=user.email, password=hashed_password)
```

I don't understand what's going on with that line.
Let's leave aside that what we're assigning is clearly an insert command
rather than a select query.

Somewhere in the backend we're apparently passing around
a cleartext password, yet we invite confusion between
whether we persisted it in cleartext form or in hashed form?
That's going to be a problem for every maintenance engineer
who joins the project, and for each annual security review you conduct.

If it's an [argon2id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) hash,
then call it a `hash`.

Consider this subsequent line:

```
async def login(user: UserIn):
  user = await authenticate_user(user.email, user.password)
```

At this point, I have no idea if `user.password` denotes some
cleartext that, after a breach, could be used used to authenticate
to unrelated sites, or if it actually denotes a hashed credential.

## non-SI units

```
def access_token_expire_minutes() -> int:
```

Thank you for explaining the units very clearly; that's helpful.

Consider adjusting by a factor of 60,
so we can demote the "it's in seconds!" aspect to just a comment.

## hardcoded parameter

This is very nice:

```
import datetime as dt

def create_access_token(email: str):
  expire = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc) + dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Consider throwing that parameter into the signature as an optional kwarg:

```
def create_access_token(email: str, expire_sec: int = 30 * 60):
  expire = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc) + dt.timedelta(seconds=expire_sec)
```

nit: Use [$ black *.py](https://pypi.org/project/black)
to make this more legible, imposing "4 blanks per tab stop".

Annotating `email` as `str` is helpful, thank you.
Feel free to tell us about the `->` return type, as well.
View it with `type(encoded_jwt)`,
or use `reveal_type()` with `mypy`.

## implicit return

```
async def get_user(email: str):
    ...
    if result:
        return result
```

This isn't great.
And there's no signature annotation of a return type,
which keeps `mypy` from being as helpful as it could be.
Consider using `$ mypy --strict ...`

If `None` comes back as the result,
we just fall off the end of the function,
implicitly returning `None`.
Please tack on an explicit `return None` to such functions,
to alert maintenance engineers of the "else" behavior.

But here, the test is pointless.
Unconditionally `return result`, and you're done.
Let the signature annotation do the work of pointing
out it's an optional row we're sending back.

## cached result

Do we have "too many DB calls" that get a user?
No, I don't think so, especially since we're asking
for exact equality on an indexed column,
hopefully one that has a UNIQUE constraint on it.

But suppose the query takes more than a millisecond,
maybe the RDBMS is across a WAN link or something silly like that,
and async lookups aren't enough.
Then you might consider decorating with
[`@lru_cache(maxsize=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

If you want to enforce a timeout, write your own
[@property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)
getter, or tack on a final `def ... , epoch: int)` parameter
which will force a cache miss whenever the epoch changes.
Make the epoch be current time rounded to two seconds,
or whatever you're comfortable with.

## cipher choice

```
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"])
```

Documentation written since 2015
will typically recommend a different scheme, a
[contest winner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2).
The passlib
[guidance](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/narr/quickstart.html#recommended-hashes)
appears to be on the somewhat dated side.

It would be helpful to future maintenance engineers to add a comment
or docstring explaining the design rationale for not going with
[argon2id](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.argon2.html).

## explicit logout

Consider adding an additional column to the user table, holding a timestamp.
Use it to record the time of last login,
and pass that timestamp around when making
"is this request authenticated?" decisions.

Then your `/logout` button simply sets it
to a timestamp in January 1970, or maybe makes it NULL,
to invalidate future replay attempts of that credential.
End user will have to `/login` after that
in order to put a fresh timestamp there.